# Reinitializing a variable allocated on stack

Tags: c++, variables, initialization, stack

In the code below the `cm` variable is allocated on the stack and the `addConstraints` is the prototype of a method :

```
ConstraintManager cm(5);

void addConstraints(ConstraintManager& cm);
```

When I call addConstraints I want to reinitialize the cm variable inside the body of the function. That is call its constructor such as doing like `cm(3)`so that it is reinitialized to contain 3 instead of 5. However I am not able to do that and the only thing I can do is:

```
ConstraintManager temp(3);
cm = temp;
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a more concise way ? Thanks.

Comment: Is `cm = ConstraintManager(3);` not good enough? If not you need to show the definition of `ConstraintManager`.

Comment: If ConstraintManager is a class that you created and the 3 is a variable stored inside the class then why recreate the whole class? You could just change that one variable to 5.

Comment: Yes but I can't modify the class unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes but I can't modify the class unfortunately

If there's no direct means to change that member in the public interface of the class, that means, in my book, that you're not supposed to change it.

If you must, what you already have is the way to do it, only less verbose:

```
cm = ConstraintManager(3);
```

Comment: If there's no assignment operator, but only a no-throw constructor, you can also say: `cm.~ConstraintManager(); new (&cm) ConstraintManager(3);`